# Sudoku bool wrong

Tags: c++, boolean, sudoku

I've come close to completing something but it isn't completely perfect yet... It's suppose to verify sudoku grids as valid or invalid. I've tossed 7 grids at it and 6/7, the verifier succeeded. This is what it fails on. It should be invalid because of the 2 4's in the middle column, but my program assigns it as VALID. Can't figure out why, thanks in advance!

```
-------------------------
| 9 5 3 | 2 6 7 | 1 4 8 |
| 6 7 1 | 5 8 4 | 9 3 2 |
| 2 4 8 | 9 1 3 | 7 5 6 |
-------------------------
| 7 1 4 | 6 9 2 | 5 8 3 |
| 5 2 9 | 7 3 8 | 4 6 1 |
| 3 8 6 | 4 5 1 | 2 9 7 |
-------------------------
| 4 6 7 | 3 2 5 | 8 1 9 |
| 1 9 5 | 8 7 6 | 3 2 4 |
| 8 3 2 | 4 1 9 | 6 7 5 |
-------------------------
```

My verifier code:

```
bool Verifier::verifySolution()
{
    bool found[9];
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        // set found elements false
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            found[i] = false;

        // Loop 9 col
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            // Check if the digit in this col's been found within                
            // corresponding row
            if (found[sudo[row][col] - 1])
                return false;     // 
            else
                found[sudo[row][col] - 1] = true;    // 
        }
    }


    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int row = (x / 3) * 3; row < (x / 3) * 3 + 3; row++)
        for (int col = (y / 3) * 3; col < (y / 3) * 3 + 3; col++)
            if (row != x && col != y && found[sudo[row][col]] == sudo[x][y])
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can figure you are not validating the columns. You're validating the rows and you're validating the blocks, but not the columns.

Also you'll have to reset all the entries of your found array to false for each block (and also for each column when you get around to that part).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly why... Can't believe i forgot to check the columns and was instead confused, haha.

Answer (score 0):

1. You aren't checking the columns.  The first big row loop, just checks each row.
2. The last chunk only appears to check the 0,0 block because you haven't looped through the x,y combinations.
3. Also, you need to reclear the found flags for the second half of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly why... Can't believe i forgot to check the columns and was instead confused, haha.